# Access of outer environment variable in PlatformIO

Tags: c++, environment-variables, platformio

I'm currently struggling to "inject" some environment variables into the PlatformIO build process. Due to my dockerized stack, I manage some secrets under my root directory within an .env file. My project structure looks similar to this:

```
Project
|- .env
|- iot
|--- iot-project-1
|----- lib
|----- src
|------- main.cpp
|----- platformio.ini
|----- [...]
```

Now I want to use my environment variables from the *.env* file in my *main.cpp*.
This is what I came up with, which didn't work as expected:

**.env**

```
FOO=hello
```

**platformio.ini**

```
build_flags = '-DFOOOO=${sysenv.FOO}'
```

**main.cpp**

```
#define XSTR(x) #x
#define STR(x) XSTR(x)

const char* fo123 = STR(FOOOO);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(fo123);
}
```

Anyone got a clue of what could be a possible workaround for my case?

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of two solutions:

1. Use platfomio recommendations with **[environment variables](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/envvars.html)**

Idea described in this [blog post](https://blog.yavilevich.com/2020/09/convention-for-compile-time-configuration-of-platformio-projects/) but it is not use `.env` file

2. Use platformio recommendations with **[advanced scripting](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/advanced_scripting.html)**

**Example:**

```
Project
|- .env
|- env-extra.py
|- platformio.ini
|- src
|--- main.cpp
|- lib
```

**.env**

```
FOO=hello
```

**platformio.ini**

```
extra_scripts =
  pre:env-extra.py
```

**main.cpp**

```
#define XSTR(x) #x
#define STR(x) XSTR(x)

const char* fo123 = STR(FOO);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(fo123);
}
```

**env-extra.py**

```
from os.path import isfile
Import("env")
assert isfile(".env")
try:
  f = open(".env", "r")
  lines = f.readlines()
  envs = []
  for line in lines:
    envs.append("-D{}".format(line.strip()))
  env.Append(BUILD_FLAGS=envs)
except IOError:
  print("File .env not accessible",)
finally:
  f.close()
```

Script **env-extra.py** read your file **.env** and append **BUILD_FLAGS**